# Definition of true density

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I am reading a paper and it talks about true densities, I mean they talk about obtaining densities from data and later compare them with the true density I want to know how can I obtain a true density mathematically or if this a paremeter from previous observations, I don't understand the definition.

I appreciate any help

"Density estimates (D) were calculated using program CAPTURE for the grid data sets and program DISTANCE for the web data sets, and these results were compared to the known true densities (D) to evaluate each model’s relative mean square error, accuracy, precision, and bias. "

Comment: Seems to be [this paper](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/3100072?uid=3737864&uid=2&uid=4&sid=21106017910121).

Comment: yes it is, now i understood. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It tells you that there was "saturation trapping" which allowed a complete enumeration. Basically they trapped and counted every critter in the nature reserve!